# Not able to display page no and total page in body of SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am setting up an invoice page where I did not use any header and footer, but in the body, I want to display page no with a total page like (1 of 6).
I am using below code but still, I am getting 1 of 1 result.

Added both function in report> code section 
then added `<<Exp>>` code as
`=code.PageNumber & " of " & code.TotalPages`

```
Function PageNumber() As String    
    Return Me.Report.Globals!PageNumber    
End Function

Function TotalPages() As String   
    Return Me.Report.Globals!TotalPages    
End Function
```

Access it in the body via expression from the textbox

I expect the output 1 of 6 pages or whatever the last page no will have.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's likely you'll find a method of accessing these globals in the body of your report.  Your options on this are to implement a header or footer, or try to figure out some way to determine a page count from your query.  For example, if you know that you want 25 rows of data per page in your report, you could use SQL `ROWNUMBER` and window function to add a column indicating a page number for that set of 25.  Those are the best options available for this issue.

Comment: This will won't work for me because I am doing an additional page break on a certain piece of code.

Comment: Your only option is header or footer then.  You're asking about a well-known issue with SSRS that has been asked about all over the internet and no one has a valid working solution beyond what I mentioned.

Comment: You can try this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/243e6b82-70f5-4051-8b3f-4110f931591f/using-global-variables-page-numbers-in-the-report-body?forum=sqlreportingservices) but I don't know that it'll work quite right. It might take some additional tweaking.